# Cannot create Android application using m2e and m2e-android

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I keep getting a generic error when I try to create an Android project using the m2e-android plugins. I follow the basic steps here:
http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/

using version Archetype version 1.0.11, but each time I find that my project has an error of some sort. The project folder in Eclipse has an exclamation point on it, which I think indicates a build path error, but I have no idea where the problem lies. When I try to clean the project I get the error:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'LookAroundYou'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'MainActivity'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I have read about this error but almost every solution I have found indicates it is a problem with SVN, but I am not using SVN.

Comment: Why aren't you using Android Studio?

Comment: What version of the ADT/m2e-android are you using? Can you find a full attack trace?